# How to make a gui screen with buttons before my game

Tags: python, arcade

I'm trying to add a gui with play game, settings, and quit buttons for my basic 2d zombie shooter game for a school assessment, but when i run the code, it has this error:

```
line 195, in on_draw
    self.manager.draw()
AttributeError: 'MyGame' object has no attribute 'manager'
```

I'm pretty new to this so i have no idea why this error is happening although i know it means the mygame class has nothing called manager.

(ps: yes I'musing python arcade example code)

```
import arcade
import random
import math
from typing import Tuple
import time
import arcade.gui


SPRITE_SCALING = 0.35
SPRITE_SCALING_LASER = 0.8

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720
SCREEN_TITLE = "zombier shooter"
ENEMY_COUNT = 50

BULLET_SPEED = 30
MOVEMENT_SPEED = 5
SPRITE_SPEED = 1

INDICATOR_BAR_OFFSET = 32
ENEMY_ATTACK_COOLDOWN = 1
PLAYER_HEALTH = 5

class QuitButton(arcade.gui.UIFlatButton):
    def on_click(self, event: arcade.gui.UIOnClickEvent):
        arcade.exit()

class MyWindow(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(800, 600, "UIFlatButton Example", resizable=True)

        # --- Required for all code that uses UI element,
        # a UIManager to handle the UI.
        self.manager = arcade.gui.UIManager()
        self.manager.enable()

        # Set background color
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.DARK_BLUE_GRAY)

        # Create a vertical BoxGroup to align buttons
        self.v_box = arcade.gui.UIBoxLayout()

        # Create the buttons
        start_button = arcade.gui.UIFlatButton(text="Start Game", width=200)
        self.v_box.add(start_button.with_space_around(bottom=20))

        settings_button = arcade.gui.UIFlatButton(text="Settings", width=200)
        self.v_box.add(settings_button.with_space_around(bottom=20))

        # Again, method 1. Use a child class to handle events.
        quit_button = QuitButton(text="Quit", width=200)
        self.v_box.add(quit_button)

        # --- Method 2 for handling click events,
        # assign self.on_click_start as callback
        start_button.on_click = self.on_click_start

        # --- Method 3 for handling click events,
        # use a decorator to handle on_click events
        @settings_button.event("on_click")
        def on_click_settings(event):
            print("Settings:", event)

        # Create a widget to hold the v_box widget, that will center the buttons
        self.manager.add(
            arcade.gui.UIAnchorWidget(
                anchor_x="center_x",
                anchor_y="center_y",
                child=self.v_box)
        )

    

class Player(arcade.Sprite):

    def update(self):
        """ moves the player """
        # move player.
        self.center_x += self.change_x
        self.center_y += self.change_y

        # check for out of bounds
        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0
        elif self.right > SCREEN_WIDTH - 1:
            self.right = SCREEN_WIDTH - 1

        if self.bottom < 0:
            self.bottom = 0
        elif self.top > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1:
            self.top = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1

class Enemy(arcade.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the enemies on our screen. 
    """

    def follow_sprite(self, player_sprite):
        """
        This function will move the current sprite towards whatever
        other sprite is specified as a parameter.
        """

        if self.center_y < player_sprite.center_y:
            self.center_y += min(SPRITE_SPEED, player_sprite.center_y - self.center_y)
        elif self.center_y > player_sprite.center_y:
            self.center_y -= min(SPRITE_SPEED, self.center_y - player_sprite.center_y)

        if self.center_x < player_sprite.center_x:
            self.center_x += min(SPRITE_SPEED, player_sprite.center_x - self.center_x)
        elif self.center_x > player_sprite.center_x:
            self.center_x -= min(SPRITE_SPEED, self.center_x - player_sprite.center_x)



class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    """
    main game class
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        """
        initialises stuff
        """

        #call the parent class initializer
        super().__init__(width, height, title)

        #variables that will hold sprite lists
        self.player_list = None

        #set up the player info
        self.player_sprite = None


        #track the current state of what key is pressed

        self.left_pressed = False

        self.right_pressed = False

        self.up_pressed = False

        self.down_pressed = False

        


        #set the background color
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.AMAZON)

    def setup(self):
        """ Set up the game and initialize the variables. """

        #sprite lists
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.enemy_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()

        #setup score
        self.score = 0
        self.score_text = None

        #setup health info
        self.health = 5
        self.health_text = None
        self.dead = None


        #set up the player
        self.player_sprite = Player(":resources:images/animated_characters/female_person/femalePerson_idle.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
        self.player_sprite.center_x = 50
        self.player_sprite.center_y = 50
        self.player_list.append(self.player_sprite)

        

        for i in range(ENEMY_COUNT):
            
            #enemy texture
            enemy = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/animated_characters/zombie/zombie_idle.png", SPRITE_SCALING)

            enemy.center_x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
            enemy.center_y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)

            self.enemy_list.append(enemy)

    def on_draw(self):
        """ render the screen. """

        #clear the screen
        self.clear()

        self.manager.draw()

        #draw all the sprites.
        self.player_list.draw()
        self.enemy_list.draw()
        self.bullet_list.draw()

        #put score text on the screen
        output = f"Score: {self.score}"
        arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 20, arcade.color.WHITE, 14)

        #put helth text on the screen
        output = f"Health: {self.health}"
        arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 40, arcade.color.WHITE, 14)

        if self.health <= 0:
            self.player_sprite.remove_from_sprite_lists()
            #put u died text on the screen
            output = f"YOU DIED"
            arcade.draw_text(output, 500, 400, arcade.color.RED, 50)
            output = f"Click to Exit"
            arcade.draw_text(output, 550, 300, arcade.color.BLACK, 30)
            

    def on_click_start(self, event):
        print("Start:", event)


    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        """ Called whenever the mouse button is clicked. """

        if self.health <= 0:
            exit()

        #create a bullet
        bullet = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/space_shooter/laserBlue01.png", SPRITE_SCALING_LASER)

        # Position the bullet at the player's current location
        start_x = self.player_sprite.center_x
        start_y = self.player_sprite.center_y
        bullet.center_x = start_x
        bullet.center_y = start_y

        # Get from the mouse the destination location for the bullet
        # IMPORTANT! If you have a scrolling screen, you will also need
        # to add in self.view_bottom and self.view_left.
        dest_x = x
        dest_y = y

        # Do math to calculate how to get the bullet to the destination.
        # Calculation the angle in radians between the start points
        # and end points. This is the angle the bullet will travel.
        x_diff = dest_x - start_x
        y_diff = dest_y - start_y
        angle = math.atan2(y_diff, x_diff)

        # Angle the bullet sprite so it doesn't look like it is flying
        # sideways.
        bullet.angle = math.degrees(angle)
        print(f"Bullet angle: {bullet.angle:.2f}")

        # Taking into account the angle, calculate our change_x
        # and change_y. Velocity is how fast the bullet travels.
        bullet.change_x = math.cos(angle) * BULLET_SPEED
        bullet.change_y = math.sin(angle) * BULLET_SPEED

        # Add the bullet to the appropriate lists
        self.bullet_list.append(bullet)


    def update_player_speed(self):



        #calculate speed based on the keys pressed

        self.player_sprite.change_x = 0

        self.player_sprite.change_y = 0



        if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed:

            self.player_sprite.change_y = MOVEMENT_SPEED

        elif self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed:

            self.player_sprite.change_y = -MOVEMENT_SPEED

        if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:

            self.player_sprite.change_x = -MOVEMENT_SPEED

        elif self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:

            self.player_sprite.change_x = MOVEMENT_SPEED


    def on_update(self, delta_time):
        """ updates values n stuff """

        #call update to move the sprite
        self.player_list.update()

         # Call update on all sprites
        self.bullet_list.update()

        # go through each bullet
        for bullet in self.bullet_list:

            #check each bullet to see if it hit a zombie
            hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(bullet, self.enemy_list)

            #if it did, remove the bullet 
            if len(hit_list) > 0:
                bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()

            # for each enemy we hit with a bullet, remove enemy and add to the score
            for enemy in hit_list:
                enemy.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                self.score += 1

            # if bullet goes off screen, then remove it
            if bullet.bottom > self.width or bullet.top < 0 or bullet.right < 0 or bullet.left > self.width:
                bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()

        for enemy in self.enemy_list:
            Enemy.follow_sprite(enemy, self.player_sprite)

        # create a list of all sprites that had a collision with the player.
        hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite, self.enemy_list)

        # go through each sprite, if it got hit, then remove the sprite and lower score and health
        for enemy in hit_list:
            enemy.remove_from_sprite_lists()
            self.score -= 1
            self.health -= 1

       
        
        
            
        


    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):

        """called when user presses a key. """



        if key == arcade.key.UP:

            self.up_pressed = True

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:

            self.down_pressed = True

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:

            self.left_pressed = True

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:

            self.right_pressed = True

            self.update_player_speed()



    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):

        """called when user releases a key. """



        if key == arcade.key.UP:

            self.up_pressed = False

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:

            self.down_pressed = False

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:

            self.left_pressed = False

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:

            self.right_pressed = False

            self.update_player_speed()



def main():
    """ Main function """
    window = MyGame(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have `MyWindow` and `MyGame` being separate classes, but that's the issue.  `self.manager` is part of `MyWindow`, and you're trying to call it from `MyGame`.

Comment: i dont understand, how would i put one class into another?

Answer (score 2):

[Tim Roberts is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72681018/python-arcade-im-trying-to-make-a-gui-screen-with-buttons-before-my-game#comment128383022_72681018). You have to merge `MyWindow` and `MyGame` classes. Take a look:

```
import arcade
import random
import math
import arcade.gui

SPRITE_SCALING = 0.35
SPRITE_SCALING_LASER = 0.8

SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400
SCREEN_TITLE = "zombier shooter"
ENEMY_COUNT = 10

BULLET_SPEED = 30
MOVEMENT_SPEED = 5
SPRITE_SPEED = 1

INDICATOR_BAR_OFFSET = 32
ENEMY_ATTACK_COOLDOWN = 1
PLAYER_HEALTH = 5

SCENE_MENU = 'SCENE_MENU'
SCENE_GAME = 'SCENE_GAME'


class QuitButton(arcade.gui.UIFlatButton):
    def on_click(self, event: arcade.gui.UIOnClickEvent):
        arcade.exit()


class Player(arcade.Sprite):

    def update(self):
        """ moves the player """
        # move player.
        self.center_x += self.change_x
        self.center_y += self.change_y

        # check for out of bounds
        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0
        elif self.right > SCREEN_WIDTH - 1:
            self.right = SCREEN_WIDTH - 1

        if self.bottom < 0:
            self.bottom = 0
        elif self.top > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1:
            self.top = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1


class Enemy(arcade.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the enemies on our screen.
    """

    def follow_sprite(self, player_sprite):
        """
        This function will move the current sprite towards whatever
        other sprite is specified as a parameter.
        """

        if self.center_y < player_sprite.center_y:
            self.center_y += min(SPRITE_SPEED, player_sprite.center_y - self.center_y)
        elif self.center_y > player_sprite.center_y:
            self.center_y -= min(SPRITE_SPEED, self.center_y - player_sprite.center_y)

        if self.center_x < player_sprite.center_x:
            self.center_x += min(SPRITE_SPEED, player_sprite.center_x - self.center_x)
        elif self.center_x > player_sprite.center_x:
            self.center_x -= min(SPRITE_SPEED, self.center_x - player_sprite.center_x)


class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    """
    main game class
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        """
        initialises stuff
        """

        # call the parent class initializer
        super().__init__(width, height, title)

        self.scene = SCENE_MENU

        # variables that will hold sprite lists
        self.player_list = None

        # set up the player info
        self.player_sprite = None

        # track the current state of what key is pressed

        self.left_pressed = False

        self.right_pressed = False

        self.up_pressed = False

        self.down_pressed = False

        # set the background color
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.AMAZON)

        # --- Required for all code that uses UI element,
        # a UIManager to handle the UI.
        self.manager = arcade.gui.UIManager()
        self.manager.enable()

        # Set background color
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.DARK_BLUE_GRAY)

        # Create a vertical BoxGroup to align buttons
        self.v_box = arcade.gui.UIBoxLayout()

        # Create the buttons
        start_button = arcade.gui.UIFlatButton(text="Start Game", width=200)
        self.v_box.add(start_button.with_space_around(bottom=20))

        settings_button = arcade.gui.UIFlatButton(text="Settings", width=200)
        self.v_box.add(settings_button.with_space_around(bottom=20))

        # Again, method 1. Use a child class to handle events.
        quit_button = QuitButton(text="Quit", width=200)
        self.v_box.add(quit_button)

        # --- Method 2 for handling click events,
        # assign self.on_click_start as callback
        start_button.on_click = self.on_click_start

        # --- Method 3 for handling click events,
        # use a decorator to handle on_click events
        @settings_button.event("on_click")
        def on_click_settings(event):
            print("Settings:", event)

        # Create a widget to hold the v_box widget, that will center the buttons
        self.manager.add(
            arcade.gui.UIAnchorWidget(
                anchor_x="center_x",
                anchor_y="center_y",
                child=self.v_box)
        )

    def setup(self):
        """ Set up the game and initialize the variables. """

        # sprite lists
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.enemy_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()

        # setup score
        self.score = 0
        self.score_text = None

        # setup health info
        self.health = 5
        self.health_text = None
        self.dead = None

        # set up the player
        self.player_sprite = Player(":resources:images/animated_characters/female_person/femalePerson_idle.png",
                                    SPRITE_SCALING)
        self.player_sprite.center_x = 50
        self.player_sprite.center_y = 50
        self.player_list.append(self.player_sprite)

        for i in range(ENEMY_COUNT):
            # enemy texture
            enemy = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/animated_characters/zombie/zombie_idle.png", SPRITE_SCALING)

            enemy.center_x = random.randrange(SCREEN_WIDTH)
            enemy.center_y = random.randrange(SCREEN_HEIGHT)

            self.enemy_list.append(enemy)

    def on_draw(self):
        """ render the screen. """

        # clear the screen
        self.clear()

        if self.scene == SCENE_MENU:
            self.manager.draw()

        elif self.scene == SCENE_GAME:
            # draw all the sprites.
            self.player_list.draw()
            self.enemy_list.draw()
            self.bullet_list.draw()

            # put score text on the screen
            output = f"Score: {self.score}"
            arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 20, arcade.color.WHITE, 14)

            # put helth text on the screen
            output = f"Health: {self.health}"
            arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 40, arcade.color.WHITE, 14)

            if self.health <= 0:
                self.player_sprite.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                # put u died text on the screen
                output = f"YOU DIED"
                arcade.draw_text(output, 500, 400, arcade.color.RED, 50)
                output = f"Click to Exit"
                arcade.draw_text(output, 550, 300, arcade.color.BLACK, 30)


    def on_click_start(self, event):
        self.setup()
        self.scene = SCENE_GAME
        self.manager.disable()
        print("Start:", event)

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        """ Called whenever the mouse button is clicked. """

        if self.health <= 0:
            exit()

        # create a bullet
        bullet = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/space_shooter/laserBlue01.png", SPRITE_SCALING_LASER)

        # Position the bullet at the player's current location
        start_x = self.player_sprite.center_x
        start_y = self.player_sprite.center_y
        bullet.center_x = start_x
        bullet.center_y = start_y

        # Get from the mouse the destination location for the bullet
        # IMPORTANT! If you have a scrolling screen, you will also need
        # to add in self.view_bottom and self.view_left.
        dest_x = x
        dest_y = y

        # Do math to calculate how to get the bullet to the destination.
        # Calculation the angle in radians between the start points
        # and end points. This is the angle the bullet will travel.
        x_diff = dest_x - start_x
        y_diff = dest_y - start_y
        angle = math.atan2(y_diff, x_diff)

        # Angle the bullet sprite so it doesn't look like it is flying
        # sideways.
        bullet.angle = math.degrees(angle)
        print(f"Bullet angle: {bullet.angle:.2f}")

        # Taking into account the angle, calculate our change_x
        # and change_y. Velocity is how fast the bullet travels.
        bullet.change_x = math.cos(angle) * BULLET_SPEED
        bullet.change_y = math.sin(angle) * BULLET_SPEED

        # Add the bullet to the appropriate lists
        self.bullet_list.append(bullet)

    def update_player_speed(self):

        # calculate speed based on the keys pressed

        self.player_sprite.change_x = 0

        self.player_sprite.change_y = 0

        if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed:

            self.player_sprite.change_y = MOVEMENT_SPEED

        elif self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed:

            self.player_sprite.change_y = -MOVEMENT_SPEED

        if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:

            self.player_sprite.change_x = -MOVEMENT_SPEED

        elif self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:

            self.player_sprite.change_x = MOVEMENT_SPEED

    def on_update(self, delta_time):
        """ updates values n stuff """

        if self.scene == SCENE_GAME:

            # call update to move the sprite
            self.player_list.update()

            # Call update on all sprites
            self.bullet_list.update()

            # go through each bullet
            for bullet in self.bullet_list:

                # check each bullet to see if it hit a zombie
                hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(bullet, self.enemy_list)

                # if it did, remove the bullet
                if len(hit_list) > 0:
                    bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()

                # for each enemy we hit with a bullet, remove enemy and add to the score
                for enemy in hit_list:
                    enemy.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                    self.score += 1

                # if bullet goes off screen, then remove it
                if bullet.bottom > self.width or bullet.top < 0 or bullet.right < 0 or bullet.left > self.width:
                    bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()

            for enemy in self.enemy_list:
                Enemy.follow_sprite(enemy, self.player_sprite)

            # create a list of all sprites that had a collision with the player.
            hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(self.player_sprite, self.enemy_list)

            # go through each sprite, if it got hit, then remove the sprite and lower score and health
            for enemy in hit_list:
                enemy.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                self.score -= 1
                self.health -= 1

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):

        """called when user presses a key. """

        if key == arcade.key.UP:

            self.up_pressed = True

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:

            self.down_pressed = True

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:

            self.left_pressed = True

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:

            self.right_pressed = True

            self.update_player_speed()

    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):

        """called when user releases a key. """

        if key == arcade.key.UP:

            self.up_pressed = False

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.DOWN:

            self.down_pressed = False

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.LEFT:

            self.left_pressed = False

            self.update_player_speed()

        elif key == arcade.key.RIGHT:

            self.right_pressed = False

            self.update_player_speed()


def main():
    """ Main function """
    MyGame(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

[image: GUI]

Comment: i have it working now, but if i click the area where the quit button is even after the game has started, it quits. how do i fix?

Comment: @riley Fixed. See my updated code